# Ubuntu 64bit - Best way to install Python 32bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, python

**I'm running Ubuntu 10.4 64bit, and I would like to run python 32bit.
The current Python version used is the 64bit one.**

---

**What can be some good ways for installing the python 32bit version without compromising the OS.** I'm kind of new to this, so I don't really know if I could substitute the python version, or know how to make it available by using short commands such as python or easy_install.

Help would be awesome. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really as easy as it, in principle, could be..

If you want all the benefits of package management and such, the easiest option is probably to install a 32-bit virtual machine.

Otherwise, you can always compile python yourself and install it under your home directory. This will however get tedious if you want lots of extra packages.

Of course, one could argue that the reason why nobody has bothered to make it any easier is that the vast majority of users have no need for a 32-bit python on an otherwise 64-bit system.